# Wrapper around `picture` environment causes page break

Tags: macros, environments, page-breaking

A `picture` environment at exactly the size of the text area can fit snugly on one page. However when I replace the environment with a wrapper environment with exactly the same definition, it takes two pages instead! This is a problem because I need to define my custom full-page environment but it is critical that an extra page not be inserted after it.

To be precise, the following compiles into one page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\newenvironment{wrap}{
  \begin{picture}(6.5,9)
}{
  \end{picture}
}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}

%\begin{wrap}
%\end{wrap}

\begin{picture}(6.5,9)
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

However if you comment out `\begin{picture}...\end{picture}` and un-comment `\begin{wrap}...\end{wrap}`, it compiles into two pages, even though it has exactly the same definition. Why is this the case?

**Narrowing it down:** replacing `9` with `8.5` solves the problem, that is, both `wrap` and `picture` versions compile to one page. So it seems that the problem is that while the 9-inch `picture` environment maxes out the space, while the `wrap` environment adds an extra sliver of space from `\newenvironment` that causes a page break. Can someone verify this guess?

Comment: you need `%` at the end of some of your lines in your `newenvironment`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines

Comment: You're missing the common `%` at the ends of your `wrap` environment. It should look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ap76G.png).

Comment: your environment is equivalent to `\space\begin{picture}...\end{picture}\space` which is two word spaces wider than the picture environment.